# {LARAVEL} How to Create a timer for claim reward?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, count

My Name is Adhetya - I'm making a new project related to games in Laravel.
I want to ask if anyone here understands or has ever made a project about a game?
First thing is, I want to make rewards every hour using laravel.

I have implemented a simple countdown with javascript and database queries.

This javascript I use:

```
<script>
 var countDownDate = new Date("{!! $rewards !!}").getTime();
 var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
     var distance = countDownDate - now;
     var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
     var confirmButton = document.getElementById("bonus");
     confirmButton.innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Second Later";
     if (distance < 0) {
         clearInterval(x);
         confirmButton.className = "btn btn-success btn-raised btn-lg";
         confirmButton.innerHTML = "Claim Now! <i class='fad fa-check-double'>";
         confirmButton.setAttribute('href','{{route('userDailyBonus')}}');
     }
 }, 1000);
</script>
```

Just info, $rewards
is what I took from the query $ user->bonus
$user->bonus
is a query that is intended so that members can only claim at that time.
I'm validated this with ($user->bonus < $now )
Are there other ways to help me and be more effective?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know anything about Laravel, but if you're working on a game that relies on (live) server side data, I'd go for a websocket. That way you don't have to rely on client side timers (which would make it a lot easier to cheat, unless you verify datetime with your database). Websockets have the advantage that you can push events to the client instead of needing the client to request them. Using ReactPHP, you can have timers running in PHP. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) is an interesting PHP websocket.

Comment: If you are familiar with `socket.io`, email me, I am working on an interesting project to integrate `socket.io` and `laravel` in a more easy and effective way than `laravel-echo-server`.

Comment: I have caught this problem, from several of the things above. I just learned that Carbon::now() defaults to UTC, So I have problem with countdown bcoz not same with time system